# How to make session data stay for only two requests

Tags: session, grails

Grails : I want some data to exist for two consequential redirects only. If I use sessions, it will stay for as long as the user's browser is open or even longer sometimes. If I use flash it will only go until the next gsp file is rendered. My controller A redirects to another controller B with some data. The data is stored until B's view b.gsp is rendered. Now inside b.gsp the user will fill in some form and submit it to send another request to another action in B. I want the data from A to stay until this point and no more. (Two requests right? One redirect and another submit).

```
class AController {

    def callBWithSomeData() {

        redirect (controller: "B", action: "showB", params: [data: "id"])
    }

    def backFromB() {

        def myDataBack = params.persistingdDataForARoundTrip
    }
}

class BController {

    def showB() {

        def data = params.data

        render "b"
    }

    def fromBtoA() {

        redirect (controller: "A", action: "backFromB", params: [persistingdDataForARoundTrip: "id"])
    }
}
```

Okay you might say, why not put it in the session and clean that session entry once the request goes back to A. But then what if the user went to b.gsp and for some reason navigated to some other page without submitting the data in which case the session data is not cleaned. It stays in the system and that ruins a few things in my app.

Or you might say, why not use flash, put a hidden field inside b.gsp with value passed from A through flash and get it submitted on the next request to B's second action. But no; assume that for some reason I don't have access to b.gsp (B and b.gsp are parts of a completely separate system). I can't mess with them.

I tried to read about web flows and subflows in grails, but I couldn't see how that can be helpful. Webflows work within the same controller I guess (I am not sure though).

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Traveling so I can't post a full answer, but I think the One Time Data plugin would work very well for you: https://grails.org/plugin/one-time-data

Answer (score 0):

Consider using grails [chain](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/ref/Controllers/chain.html). According to the docs:

> [Chain] uses flash storage to implicitly retain the model following an HTTP redirect from one action to another.

and can be used as:

```
def one() {
    chain action: 'two', model: [name: 'Tony', town: 'Birmingham']
}

def two() {
    [name: 'Anthony', country: 'England']
}
```

Comment: looks promising. I will give a try and get back to you